# Isomorphism of Quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, group-isomorphism

I have the following question on an abstract algebra assignment:

> Show that for m,n non-zero positive integers
>   $$Z/mZ\times Z⁄nZ\cong Z⁄mnZ$$
>   if and only if m and n are relatively prime, that is, $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Initially, I was going to use $Z/mZ$, $Z/nZ$, and $Z/nmZ$ with the operation fo addition, but thought it might be more interesting take them with multiplication. My draft solution is:

> We will show that $Z⁄mZ\times Z⁄nZ\cong Z⁄mnZ$ if and only if
>   $\gcd(m,n)=1$. We shall denote any quotient group of the form $Z⁄kZ$
>   as $Z_k$. Take $Z_m$, $Z_n$ and $Z_{mn}$ with the operation of
>   multiplication. Define $\varphi$ as the function $$\varphi:Z_{mn}\to Z_m\times Z_n,\quad [x]_{mn}\to([x]_m,[x]_n).$$ We now show that
>   $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.
>   $$φ([x]_{mn}[y]_{mn})=φ([xy]_{mn})=([xy]_m,[xy]_n)=([x]_m,[x]_n )([y]_m,[y]_n )=\varphi([x]_{mn})φ([y]_{mn}).$$ 
>   Hence $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.
>
> Now, the kernel of $\varphi$ is 
>   $$\text{ker}\varphi=\{x∈Z_{mn}\,|\,\varphi(x)=([e]_m,[e]_n)=([1]_m,[1]_n
> > )\}.$$ This gives the system of congruences $$x\equiv 1 \mod{m}$$
>   $$x\equiv 1 \mod{n}.$$ Solutions to the above system can be found
>   using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which shows that the number of
>   solutions will be $\gcd(m,n)$. The solutions have the form
>   $x_j=(j-1)\times\text{lcm}(m,n)+1$ for each $j\in\{1,...,\gcd(m,n)\}$.
>   We shall now assess two cases for the possible values of $\gcd(m,n)$.
>
> **Case 1**: In the case where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we have $\gcd(m,n)=1$, so there is one solution to the system of
>   congruences, and the solution is
>   $$x_1=(1-1)\times\text{lcm}(m,n)+1=1.$$ Hence
>   $\text{ker}\varphi=\{1\}=\{e\}$ and the kernel is trivial. It follows
>   that $\varphi$ is injective. We also know that
>   $|{Z_m×Z_n}|=|{Z_{mn}}|=mn$, so it must be the case that $\varphi$ is
>   surjective. We have that $\varphi$ is bijective, and thus $\varphi$ is
>   an isomorphism.
>
> **Case 2**: In the case where $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, we have $\gcd(m,n)>1$, so there are multiple solutions to the system of
>   congruences. It follows that the kernel of $\varphi$ is non-trivial,
>   hence $\varphi$ is not injective, and thus $\varphi$ cannot be an
>   isomorphism.
>
> Therefore, we have shown that $Z⁄mZ\times Z⁄nZ$ is isomorphic to
>   $Z⁄{mnZ}$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

I was hoping you could have a look over my solution and let me know if it's correct, or if not, where I've made mistakes.

Comment: There is no mistake that I can see, however, for most people, Chinese Remainder theorem (that you use here) usually denotes the assertion you are trying to prove.

Comment: I'm just wondering ... do you meant you "just write" the group operation on $\mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}$ multiplicatively? Because it is not a group under multiplication for general $m$.

Comment: I had forgotten originally that Z/mZ was not a group (because it doesn't have inverses). The question doesn't really require that it is a group, so I guess I'm trying to show that they are a monoid isomorphism.

Comment: @Zac You actually get a ring homomorphism since $[x+y]=[x]+[y]$.

Comment: I've been thinking about this a little further overnight, and my concern is that for monoids, the kernel being trivial does not imply that $\varphi$ is injective.